# Пунктуация. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

"Концепция данного устройства основана на улавливании храпа, услышав который(,) надетый на руку браслет бьет слабым током спящего".

Здравствуйте, дорогие знатоки Великого и Могучего! Нужна ли запятая, указанная в скобках?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно без запятой.

[**Деепричастные конструкции**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113) (справочник Розенталя):

> **Примечание.** Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется:
> <...>
> **4)** если деепричастие имеет в качестве зависимого слова союзное слово ***который*** в составе определительной придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения (такое деепричастие от придаточной части запятой не отделяется): *Перед старыми заводами возникали десятки серьёзных проблем, **не решив которые невозможно было перейти к новым методам постройки кораблей*** (Коч.); *Направо была дверь, **пройдя которую можно было попасть в коридор,** ведущий на сцену; Опубликованы новые произведения молодого писателя, **читая которые нетрудно видеть его творческий рост.***

Произносительная пауза после ***который*** также не даёт оснований для постановки запятой.

Comment: Стилистика нехороша. И еще интересно: во всех примерах безличные предложения. Это случайно?

Comment: @Sharon Я заметил безличные. Но возьмите любое личное придаточное -- запятой всё равно не будет. Стилистика как стилистика...

Comment: Ну, безличные предложения пусть пока останутся под вопросом, хотя тоже странно это. А стилистика вот чем мне не нравится: «который надетый на руку браслет». Совпадение двух определительных  и рядом стоящих форм и оборот в препозиции, отдаляющий определяемое существительное. А вот его, кстати,  в безличных примерах у Розенталя вообще нет.

Comment: Ну и что, что нет? В спавочниках вообще много чего нет. *Опубликованы новые произведения молодого писателя, читая которые вы непременно откроете для себя...*  Я, конечно, согласен с вами насчёт "рядом стоящих", но предложение понимается однозначно, да и об этом не спрашивалось.

Comment: Ну тогда вс в порядке, я зря сомневалась. А оборот вам тоже не мешает? К тому же я говорю и стилистических погрешностях, с грамматикой и запятой все нормально.  За грамматику и пунктуацию я поставлю вам плюс.

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо! Надо будет переделать предложение -- переделаем!

Comment: "Концепция данного устройства основана на улавливании храпа, услышав который браслет, надетый на руку, бьет слабым током спящего". Так нормально стилистически?

Comment: "Концепция данного устройства основана на улавливании характерных звуков храпа. В случае распознавания ронхопатии, браслет немедленно бьет слабым током спящего человека в районе запястья, на которое надет". Может, так лучше? Всем спасибо за ответы!

Comment: @AlexNop  Последний вариант, как по мне, звучит лучше. И Вам спасибо за вопрос! Ответы можно и нужно еще принимать галочкой (не видели мой комментарий под первым вашим вопросом?). Если ответов несколько, то галочку можно поставить только одному из них как наиболее понравившемуся и решившему проблему.

Comment: Видел Ваш комментарий. Но не нашел галочки. Со второй попытки мне это удалось :-)